# App Crashes when trying to make view draggable with protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

So I wrote a protocol to make what ever UIView that conforms it draggable. However when I test this in the simulator it crashes when I try to drag the view. and displays this in the log

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The protocol:

```
protocol Draggable {}

extension Draggable where Self: UIView {

    func wasDragged (gestrue: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gestrue.translation(in: UIScreen.main.focusedView)
        if let label = gestrue.view {

            label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

        }
        gestrue.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: UIScreen.main.focusedView)



    }

    func setGesture () {

        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: UIScreen.main, action: Selector(("wasDragged:")))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

}
```

and in a custom label class I conformed it:

```
class DraggableLabel: UILabel, Draggable {
}
```

Then I called the setGesutre function in viewDidLoad of the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    draggableLabel.setGesture()
}
```

OK I admit I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

The action `wasDragged(gesture:)` needs to be accessible for message-dispatch via the Objective-C runtime. Use the `@objc` annotation to make a method available for message dispatch. Methods of NSObject subclasses are automatically `@objc` methods.

The bad news is that this will only work for Objective-C-compatible classes or extensions. Protocol extensions like yours are not compatible, so you cannot put action methods into those extensions.

Your options are to add this functionality to a subclass or a plain class extension:

```
extension DraggableLabel {

    func wasDragged (gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gesture.translation(in: UIScreen.main.focusedView)
        center = CGPoint(x: center.x + translation.x, y: center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: UIScreen.main.focusedView)
    }

    func setGesture () {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                             action: #selector(wasDragged(sender:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

(Notice that I also changed the target of the gesture recognizer to the view instead of the main screen. Did you intend to use the responder chain to propagate the event to the right view?)

The obvious disadvantage is the reduced flexibility compared to the protocol oriented approach. If that's a problem I would look into class composition. Create a class that encapsulates the gesture recognizer and its action method. Give it a view property and configure everything when that property is set:

```
class DraggingBehavior: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView? {
        didSet {
            guard let view = view else { return }
            let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasDragged(sender:)))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }

    func wasDragged(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Was dragged")
        // put the view translation code here.
    }
}
```

The `@IBOutlet` makes this class compatible with Interface Builder. Drag in a Custom Object, set its class to `DraggingBehavior`, connect the view outlet to the view you would like to make draggable.